# Creating your own symbols in r?

Tags: r

How would I go about creating my own symbols in R, would this require creating a package for this particular purpose, if so, how would I go about implementing this? wouldn't the symbols be limited to relatively common ones, like those on the keyboard, otherwise, it would have to be spelt out. for example, imagine a vertical division sign, currently on my keyboard it would look like this `*|*` which is the best I can currently do. Is there a repository of symbols that could be used by R programming aside from those found only on the computer keyboard?

Comment: You can't do this in R. R is an interpreted language and all code is run through the build in parser. You cannot change how the the built in parser works to recognize new symbols. At best, you can change how existing symbols work. The one exception is that you can introduce infix operators with the `%<something>%`  syntax. But you could not define an operator like `*|*` in R.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are asking whether there are other *glyphs* available for use in R. We have to be careful when we talk about a "symbol" in computing, because this word has a different meaning in computer programming from the standard English meaning of "symbol".

In computing, a "symbol" is an identifier (such as a variable name or an operator) that can be read and interpreted as such by the language's parser. A *glyph* on the other hand, is a single character that can be a letter, a number, a space, a punctuation mark, or various other shapes and (as commonly understood) symbols.

It is possible to get a huge number of different *glyphs* in R, using Unicode escapes. Unicode is an international standard for encoding all types of glyphs, and you can see a [list of Unicode characters here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

So, for example, using your keyboard you can type:

```r
"6 \u00f7 2"
#> [1] "6 ÷ 2"
```

to show a division symbol, or

```r
"6 \u2052 2"
#> [1] "6 ⁒ 2"
```

or

```r
"6 \u00b7|\u00b7 2"
#> [1] "6 ·|· 2"
```

Now the caveat is that while it is fine to use these "symbols" (English sense) in character strings, you can't properly use them as "symbols" (computer sense) in R because of how the parser works. It is possible to name a variable or a function with them, but they need to be wrapped in back ticks, and cannot be used as binary operators (such replacing the division symbol with one of them)

The closest you come is using the `%operator%` syntax like this:

```r
`%·|·%` <- `/`

6 %·|·% 2
#> [1] 3
```

Which is complex and ugly enough to be next to useless for this purpose.